# Using two redux actions when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Sounds like something simple enough, but redux is just so darn confusing.

As it is now, I have a list of buttons created based off of a reducer object, and when I click one of them, I make a get request which return me an object, which I then render accordingly.

What I would like to add is the name of the button clicked and use it as a title to what is created from the get request.

Here is my current code:

```
//containers/module-buttons.js
//where the buttons are creared and bound to an action
//fetchLogs(moduleUrl) is with the get request I am making
class ModuleButtons extends Component{
    createListItems(){
        return this.props.modules.map((module)=>{
            return (
                <ListGroupItem bsStyle="warning" key ={module.id}
                               onClick={()=>this.props.fetchLogs(module.url)}>
                                {module.name}</ListGroupItem>
            );
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <ListGroup>
                {this.createListItems()}
            </ListGroup>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        modules: state.modules

    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({fetchLogs: fetchLogs}, dispatch);
}

//containers/module-log.js
//whenever a button is clicked, the json object from the get request is rendered here
//what I want to do it in the <h3> tags put the name of the button previously clicked.
class ModuleLog extends Component{

    render(){
        if (!this.props.module){
            return <Panel><h5>Please select a module</h5></Panel>;
        }
        else{
            const renderData = Object.keys(this.props.module)
            .map((mainKey, key )=> <Log mainKey={mainKey}
                      innerObject={this.props.module[mainKey]} key={key} />);
            return (
                <div>
                    <h3>[insert module name here]</h3>
                    <ul>{renderData}</ul>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
      module: state.moduleLog
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ModuleLog);

// actions/actions.js
export const moduleClicked = (module) =>{
    return {
        type: "MODULE_CLICKED",
        payload: module
    }
}

export function fetchLogs(moduleUrl){
    console.log(moduleUrl);
    const request = axios.get(moduleUrl);
    return (dispatch) => {
        request.then(({data}) =>{
            dispatch({type: 'FETCH_MODULES', payload: data});
        });
    };
}
```

Edit: added the code in the actions.js file.

Comment: Can you add the code that you currently have for fetchLogs? Not very clear from the question. Do you just want fetchLogs to take an additional argument? Do you want to emit an action after fetchLogs fetches the data?

Comment: @iamnat I added the fetchLogs function as well as the other action that I used to use to access my modules reducer.
Before I had the fetchLogs, I used moduleClicked as a test to display the name of the module, which worked fine. What I would like to do is use that in addition to the fetchLogs simply to display the name. So basically, just an additional action since it is  ready to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just add an extra argument to fetchLogs and then dispatch another action?

```
<ListGroupItem 
  bsStyle="warning" key ={module.id}
  onClick={()=>this.props.fetchLogs(module.url, module.name)}>
    {module.name}
</ListGroupItem>
```

And hence:

```
//actions.js

export function fetchLogs(moduleUrl, moduleName){
    console.log(moduleUrl);
    const request = axios.get(moduleUrl);
    return (dispatch) => {
        request.then(({data}) =>{
            dispatch({type: 'FETCH_MODULES', payload: data});
            dispatch({type: 'MODULE_CLICKED', payload: moduleName});
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: It kinda worked after messing around a bit. I am now having the problem that for some reason the action is returning the array of objects as opposed to just the one clicked. I'll keep messing around and hopefully it will be figured out.

Thanks for the help!